# Shopify - Messenger - Change Icon with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, shopify

Shopify recently added this feature to contact store owners through messenger.  My client would like me to change the appearance of this icon, making it their branded icon instead.

[image]

The JavaScript that makes this appear runs a few seconds after the page is done loading and any code I make to alter it won't work.  I'm looking for a place to put my code so that it will run AFTER the messenger app's code is finished.

Any suggestions on how to make this happen?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried periodically alter this icon? Like setTimout? I know, it's not a good idea :)

Comment: I thought about it, but the timing doesn't seem consistent and I'm sure there would be a noticeable moment before it changes...

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the button using the themes editor:
https://help.shopify.com/manual/sell-online/facebook-messenger/message-us-button

If you want another button a custom made button or graphics you will have to modify the style/css and create your desired design.